# Custom Permalinks works only on some posts

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I changed my WordPress site to use Post Name Permalink setting. But only some posts are loading with the www.example.com/post-name format. There is a good percentage of posts that loads with the ww.example.com/post-id.

I have looked and compared the posts and cannot find anything special in invalid posts. They all have valid titles.

What else should I be looking at to fix this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go and "re-save" your permalinks options, go to Settings > Permalinks and set it to one of the defaults - save it - and then set it back to how you'd like them to look and save it again. You may also look at the [`flush_rewrite_rules()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules) function, especially if you've added any custom post types or inserted any posts with plugins or the [`wp_insert_post()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post) function.

Edit: Since you are using custom post types, try a flushing function like this:

```
function flush_rewrite_on_save_my_custom_post_type(){
    xhynk_register_my_custom_post_type(); //The function used to register the custom post type
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
```

and hook it to the [`save_post()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post) hook

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'flush_rewrite_on_save_my_custom_post_type' );
// or
add_action( 'save_post_my_custom_post_type', 'flush_rewrite_on_save_my_custom_post_type' );
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.I tried re-saving permalink option several times by change different default options. But that did not fix the issue. I created a custom post type, but not actively using it as of yet. Do you think just having a custom post type in the system, is causing the issue?

Comment: Ohh... and to answer to last part of your question all the posts were automatically created from an XML file using the WP All Import plugin.

Comment: I do actually. Can you post the code you've used to make the custom post type? For now, you could try commenting out the code for the custom post type and then re-save permalinks again and see if that fixes your issue. If it does, the issue is in your implementation.

Comment: I've added an edit on how you can flush rewrite rules when you save your custom post type, which can cause permalink issues

Comment: Let me try your suggestions. [Here](https://gist.github.com/dhanushka-samarakoon/ef4d9e1ae48c39a2d2d373a36dad1374) is the code I use to create the custom post type. I'm using the code as a custom plugin. This plugin is currently deactivated since I'm not planning on using the new custom post type in near future.

Comment: I removed the custom code plugin and got rid of the custom post type as well. Then tried switching back and forth between multiple default permalink options. But still, the issue remains the same. 
Do I still need to run the flush_rewrite_rules even if I'm not using a custom post type anymore?

Comment: I added the flush_rewrite_rules() to the functions.php on the theme and did a refresh, but that didn't help either.